# Problem with @Indexed annotations in hibernate search

Tags: hibernate-search, indexed

I'm actually trying to deploy HibernateSearch in a J2EE application. I have imported some dependencies I've seen on tuto's :

```
<!-- HIBERNATE DEPENDENCIES -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
<version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
<version>${commons-dbcp.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Hibernate Search -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
<version>3.1.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
<version>3.3.0.ga</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
<version>3.4.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
<artifactId>lucene-analyzers</artifactId>
<version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

My problem is, in order to continue, I need to put the @Indexed annotation in my entity classes but I don't have access to this annotation(Eclipse doesn't know it and of course,that doesn't pass the compilation)

Could you give me some advice or lead ? Maybe I don't have the good dependencies ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Eclipse or Maven but I can confirm that in my project that uses Hibernate Search 3.3.0 that the Indexed annotation does definitely exist in the hibernate-search-3.3.0.Final JAR. Try update your dependencies to use the latest JAR. There is definitely nothing else that you need to use this annotation though.